# How to remove repeated elements in a vector, similar to 'set' in Python

Tags: python, r, duplicates

I have a vector with repeated elements, and would like to remove them so that each element appears only once.

In Python I could construct a [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) from a vector to achieve this, but how can I do this in R?

Comment: Can you give some example data to illustrate what you mean by "repeating". Not all R users will have any idea what "just 'feed' a vector to a set" in python means. By repeating do you mean duplicate or contiguous repeats? For the former see `?duplicated`

Comment: To remove contiguous repeats only, using an example form an answer below `v <- c(1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3)`, you can compare the vector with a shifted version of itself: `v[c(TRUE, !v[-length(v)] == v[-1])]`. It will return `1 5 2 6 1 3`, keeping the second repeated `1` that is not contiguous to the first ones.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can check out [`unique`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) function.

```
 > v = c(1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3)
 > unique(v)
 [1] 1 5 2 6 3
```

Answer (score 11):

This does the same thing. Slower, but useful if you also want a logical vector of the duplicates:

```
v[duplicated(v)]
```

Comment: this also has the potential to preserve names in a named vector, whereas `unique` just drops them.

Comment: This is good, though if you want to actually _remove_ the elements yyou should do `v[!duplicated(v)]`. In this case it will always keep the first of the duplicate, I wonder if there is a way to change that (and randomly choose one of the duplicate)?

Answer (score 7):

To remove contiguous duplicated elements only, you can compare the vector with a shifted version of itself:

```
v <- c(1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3)
v[c(TRUE, !v[-length(v)] == v[-1])]
[1] 1 5 2 6 1 3
```

The same can be written a little more elegantly using [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):

```
library(dplyr)
v[v != lag(v)]
[1] NA  5  2  6  1  3
```

The NA returned by [lag()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html?q=lag) removes the first value, to keep the first value, you can change the default to a value that will be different from the first value.

```
v[v != lag(v, default = !v[1])]
[1] 1 5 2 6 1 3
```